# Razorpay Dynamically get totalamount in Angular 2 not working in checkout page

Tags: angular2-template, razorpay

I have integrated razorpay into my checkout page.

I need to get the amount from my order placed, how do i get it dynamically.

Below is razorpay config.

```
public totalAmount:number;

rzp1: any;
options = {
    key: "rzp_test_m8sE9eaFkPEUHRasfm",
    amount: this.totalAmount, // Doesnt work here
    name: "Test Pvt Ltd",
    description: "Purchase Description",
    image: "../../../assets/static/hmicon.png",
    handler: function(response) {
      this.paymentId=response.razorpay_payment_id;
      this.orderanything(this.paymentId);

    },
    modal: {
    ondismiss: function() {}
    },
    prefill: {
      name: "Test",
      email: "test123@gmail.com"
    },
    notes: {
      address: "Hello World"
    },
    theme: {
      color: "#F37254"
    }
  };

 public initPay(): void {
    this.rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(this.options);
    this.rzp1.open();
    this.totalAmount=this.getTotal();
    console.log(this.totalAmount)   //here i get the total
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i achieved something like :

```
public totalAmount: number;

options = {
  key: "rzp_test_asasdsd...",
  amount: this.totalAmount,
  ...
}

public initPay(): void {
    console.log(this.totalAmount);
    this.options.amount = this.getTotal() * 100; 
    this.rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(this.options);
    this.rzp1.open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
public totalAmount: number;

options = {

     "key": 'rzp_test_wVhWYAQR2....', 

      "amount": '',

}
public numbersum: number;

public razorsum :number;

public initPay(): void {
     
console.log(this.sum);

      this.numbersum  = this.sum*100;

      this.razorsum = this.numbersum

      this.options.amount = this.razorsum;

      var rzp1 = new Razorpay(this.options);

      rzp1.open();

      console.log("works");
}
```